# parameterized query containing literal '%s'?

Tags: mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm attempting to migrate from the python package `mysqlclient` to the official Oracle `mysql-connector-python` in pure-python mode.

The former supports escaping parameter placeholders so that the below works:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo(bar, baz) VALUES (\'%%s\', %s)', ('abc',))
```

This would set bar to the literal value "%s" and baz to "abc".  `mysql-connector-python` seems to not support this sort of escaping, interprets both "%s" as parameter placeholders, and complains that there are fewer supplied parameters than there are placeholders.  Inspecting the connector code (`cursor.py`) seems to bear this out:

```
RE_PY_PARAM = re.compile(b"(%s)")
...
psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
tmp = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, tmp)
```

Is there a workaround here, other than binding the string containing the literal "%s" as a parameter?  Is there a way to build "%s" into the static query text in such a way that it doesn't look like "%s"?  Hex codes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the simplest approach:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo(bar, baz) VALUES (\'%\' \'s\', %s)', ('abc',))
```